# Are there or will be any hardware specially designed for managed code?

Tags: c#, .net, hardware

One of my colleagues told me something like that over a year ago. I was wondering if there is something like this available now or will be in the future?

I think it was gonna have a separate GC core, and some memory management thing but I am fuzzy about it.

Any clues?

Comment: This was asked only recently over on [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7380/net-processing-unit)

Answer (score 2):

Some microcontrollers support a [Jazelle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jazelle) instruction set which implements part of Java in hardware, it's not .NET but it is managed code and the same could be done for .NETMF.

Answer (score 2):

There's the http://netduino.com/netduino/ that supports the .net micro framework.

Comment: Arduino doesn't have any special support for managed code.  It runs .NETMF because .NETMF got ported to the AVR instruction set.

Comment: Ah, I thought Netduino was an alternate form of Arduino - one specifically designed for .net...thanks :)

Comment: It's different software than Arduino, but the exact same Atmel AVR processor.

Comment: Ah cool. Thanks for that - I've been reading the site and wondering what really set it apart from the Arduino but now I know...still very interested in it :)

Comment: Oh sorry!  It's not an AVR processor like Arduino, it's an ARM-base processor (doesn't appear to have Jazelle support).  Still, the .NET part of the kit is software-only.